# How to add Services to AccountController implementing Asp Identity an UnitOf work pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I run on an issue injecting service patterns in AccountController Implementing ASP.Net Identity. Here is my code:

**Account Controller Constructor**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMyProfileService _profileService;
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkAsync _unitOfWorkAsync;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set { _signInManager = value; }
    }

    private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;
    public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _roleManager = value;
        }
    }
    public AccountController()
    {      
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, 
        ApplicationRoleManager roleManager,IMyProfileService profileService ,IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWorkAsync )
    {        
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
        RoleManager = roleManager;
        _profileService = profileService;
        _unitOfWorkAsync = unitOfWorkAsync;
    }
```

but when i try to communicate with the service class like this on any method:

```
_profileService.GerProfilesByUsername(userName);
```

it gives me Null Ref Exception.. By the way here is my IOC resolution using Unity:

```
   container
            .RegisterType<IDataContextAsync, NovusTNContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
            .RegisterType<IUnitOfWorkAsync, UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
            .RegisterType<IRepositoryAsync<Education>, Repository<Education>>()
            .RegisterType<IRepositoryAsync<Profile>, Repository<Profile>>()
             .RegisterType<IRepositoryAsync<Job>, Repository<Job>>()
            .RegisterType<IEducationService, EducationService>()
            .RegisterType<IJobService, JobService>()
            .RegisterType<IMyProfileService, MyProfileService>()

            //*****************Membership Authentication Registration***************//

            .RegisterType<DbContext, MembershipContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
            .RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
            .RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
            .RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

My aim of using this is when the user registers or login i can use the profile service to create a new profile upon registration and pull up profile upon login. Any help would be valued. TIA